# How i can upload file using api in product customizable option type file magento2

Tags: api, magento2, product

i have a doubt in magento  customizable option type file.I want to upload file to magento customizable option type file using api is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "i have a doubt in magento customizable option type file"?

Answer (score 0):

First declare plugin in

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/webapi_rest/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name=""Magento\Catalog\Model\Webapi\Product\Option\Type\File\Processor">
        <plugin name="AllowFileUploadPlugin"
                type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Catalog\Webaip\ProductOptionTypeFileProcessor\AroundProcessFileContent\AllowFileUploadPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin code can look like this: https://pastebin.com/GKxBB4a9

Comment: Yes this is good one more doubt remaning how can i pass the data using rest api ?can you please specify the format...